# Opencv extra-modules link failed

Tags: c++, opencv, dll, cmake, compiler-errors

I'm trying to define my own opencv module and build it out of the sources folder, and I meet some link error while building on window's msvc:

[link error log on visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdBeY.png)

```
20>matlib.obj : error LNK2019: in function "public: class cv::Mat __cdecl cv::_InputArray::getMat_(int)const " (?getMat_@_InputArray@cv@@QEBA?AVMat@2@H@Z)"public: void __cdecl cv::matlib::transform::Inc(class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_OutputArray const &)" (?Inc@transform@matlib@cv@@QEAAXAEBV_InputArray@3@AEBV_OutputArray@3@@Z) unresolved external symbol
```

here is my file structure(on any arbitrary path):

[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGl6H.png)

I try to build this extra module(matlib.cpp) with opencv source in:
F:/opencv-master with CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(the_description "matlib module")
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "/O2")
include_directories(F:/opencv-master/modules/core/include)
include_directories(./include)
set(MODEL_SRCS matlib.cpp)
ocv_glob_module_sources(${MODEL_SRCS})
ocv_define_module(matlib WRAP python)
```

While the CMake build is success, bud when I run OpenCV.sln and build the ALL_BUILD
I meet the link error above. I know I should add some .lib path or include path in mscv settings but I don't know which one causing the error. Any Idea?

Edit:
here is the matlib.cpp

```
#include "precomp.hpp"
#include <iostream>


namespace cv {
namespace matlib {

void transform::Inc(InputArray src, OutputArray dst)
{
    cv::Mat M = src.getMat();
    int image_width = M.cols;
    int image_height = M.rows;

    std::cout << "arr in c++: " << std::endl << " "  << M << std::endl << std::endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < M.rows; i++)
    {
        double* Mi = M.ptr<double>(i);
        for(int j = 0; j < M.cols; j++)
            Mi[j] = Mi[j] + 1;
    }

    M.copyTo(dst);
}   

} // Matlib
} // cv
```

and here is the matlib.hpp: I only use opencv core.hpp

```
#ifndef __OPENCV_matlib_HPP__
#define __OPENCV_matlib_HPP__

#include "opencv2/core.hpp"


namespace cv {
namespace matlib {

class CV_EXPORTS_W transform 
{
public:
    CV_WRAP transform() {}
    virtual ~transform() {}

    CV_WRAP void Inc(InputArray src, OutputArray dst);
};
} // matlib
} // cv
#endif
```

Comment: It is a rule of the Stack Overflow that the error message should be included into the question post as **text**. *Linking* as *image* is not sufficient to fulfill that requirement. See also [ask].

Comment: Hi, @Tsyvarev thanks for noticing me that.